# to put a wordpress plugin only on selected pages

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

this is my code for word press plugin which i found on internet using this plugin i m inserting the data in mysql database ....all are working fine and correcltly and also inserting data in table....bt the html form of plug in appearing on every page ...i tried so many things bt could not get success....
so please help me that how can i get my this plug in only on selected pages (such as events.php or contact_us.php)  ....thanx in advance..... this is my index.php file for plugin....

```
wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes', plugins_url( '/js/demo.js' , __FILE__ ) , array( 'jquery' ));
    // including ajax script in the plugin Myajax.ajaxurl 
    wp_localize_script( 'inkthemes', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
    function post_word_count(){
    $name = $_POST['dname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_ajax_demo', 
        array( 
            'name' => $name,
            'lname' => $lname,
            'address' => $address,
             'email' => $email
         ), 
         array( 
            '%s','%s','%s','%s'
         ) 
    );
    die();
    return true;
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_post_word_count', 'post_word_count');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post_word_count', 'post_word_count');
    function show_form(){
    echo "<form>";
    echo "<label>First Name</label>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='dname' name='dname' value=''/><br/>";
    echo "<label>Last Name</label>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='lname' name='lname' value=''/><br/>";
    echo "<label>Address</label>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='address' name='address' value=''/><br/>";
    echo "<label>E-mail</label>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='email' name='email' value=''/><br/>";
    echo "<input type='button' id='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
    echo "</form>";
    }
    add_action('the_content', 'show_form');
     ?>`
```

here the javascript code named(demo.js)

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#submit").click(function(){
    var name = jQuery("#dname").val();
    var lname = jQuery("#lname").val();
    var address = jQuery("#address").val();
    var email = jQuery("#email").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
data: {"action": "post_word_count", "dname":name, "lname":lname, "address":address,     "email":email},
success: function(data){
alert(data);
}
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know too much about it but I've just had a quick look and you can Dequeue scripts that have been added. Have a look here 
[Wordpress.org dequeue script reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)

You could maybe add it on the pages yu don't want the script

### EDIT

Just found this little snippet that you can edit to suit

```
 function wpa_scripts() {
    // if this is not the contact page, remove the script
    if( ! is_page( 'contact-us' ) ){
        wp_dequeue_script( 'contact-form-7' );
    }
}
// adjust priority to make sure this runs after the plugins add their scripts/styles
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_scripts', 100 );
```

Comment: Thanks to Manish for pointing out my code hadn't come out right and suggesting an edit.

Comment: wp_dequeue_script( 'contact-form-7' );  sir can you please explain me this line of code i new to wordpress,is it(contact-form-7) the name of plug in???and what should i write instead of this???

Comment: I tried all the things with your given code...bt i could not get succeed....it may be  possibe that i making any mistake to put this code at right place...so please help me ....thanx in advance........

Comment: I'm afraid I.m not the best person to ask as I don't know much about it. contact-form-7 is a wp-plugin as was used as an example, change it to the plugin or theme you want to stop acting on the page.